# Is there any advantage or reason with vertical chassis switch?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

When I was looking for Cisco 6500 series chassis,
I saw that there are horizontal(6509E) and vertical chassis(6509VE).

Although 6509VE has same(or almost same) chassis height as 6513E,
but 6509VE only can hold 9 modules, which is same as 6509E.

So, is there any advantage or reason with vertical chassis switch
in spite of bigger than horizontal one?

Comment: Mostly useful for environments which require [NEBS Compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Equipment-Building_System)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big driver for the 6509-V-E is that it is a front to back air flow, rather than the side to side airflow of the 6509-E.  This is a very important feature in some data centers to maintain proper cooling.